# SQL - Count query question

Tags: sql, count

I want to know how many users answerd a question, so I made that query :

```
    SELECT answer.idAnswer, 
           answer.title, 
           answercategory.label, 
           (SUM(1)) as nbAnswer
      FROM ANSWER
INNER JOIN answerCategory ON answer.idAnswerCategory = answercategory.idAnswerCategory
 LEFT JOIN answerUser ON answer.idAnswer = answerUser.idAnswer
  GROUP BY answer.idAnswer
```

Its almost working, the only thing that doesn't work is that it's giving me "one" answer if  nobody answered the question (it means even if there are no records in answerUser). I would like to have zero instead of one in that case. If I add a "-1", when there is one answer, I'll get zero. Any idea how I can correct that?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(answerUser.idAnswer)` instead of `SUM(1)`. Count will ignore the NULL rows created by the LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `SUM(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT answer.idAnswer, answer.title, answercategory.label, count(*) as nbAnswer
FROM answer
INNER JOIN answerCategory on answer.idAnswerCategory = answercategory.idAnswerCategory
LEFT JOIN answerUser ON answer.idAnswer = answerUser.idAnswer
GROUP BY answer.idAnswer
```